# Bluetooth timeout when connecting to any devices

Tags: audio, bluetooth, nixos

My bluetooth setup was working perfectly until a few days ago, when I paired a second device (this could be a coincidence). Since this time, my machine no longer connects to any bluetooth devices. I am having trouble tracking down the problem because it seems like I get a different error message each time, but I will try to describe the behavior.

After deleting /var/lib/bluetooth and trying a clean install of the bluetooth stack, I open bluetoothctl

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
<devices omitted>
[bluetooth]# pair F2:F6:5A:BE:53:F0
```

At this point, bluetoothctl claims to be connected, but pulseaudio doesn't show the connected speaker. I can use `disconnect F2:F6:5A:BE:53:F0`, but journalctl shows

```
bluetoothd[5072]: Disconnecting failed: already disconnected
```

After this point, trying to connect again to the device results in a timeout.

Some misc errors that bluetooth puts in the log

```
bluetoothd[7750]: Sap driver initialization failed.
bluetoothd[7750]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
kernel: debugfs: File 'le_min_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
kernel: debugfs: File 'le_max_key_size' in directory 'hci0' already present!
```

I am running NixOS 20.03, kernel 5.4.41, bluetoothd 5.53. Happy to provide any more info, I just want to listen to sounds from my computer again.